# Linear map of derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ be the vector field of all polynomials in $\mathbb{R}$ of degree at most $3$. If $T:V\rightarrow V$ is the linear map that sends a polynomial $p(x)$ to $p(x)+p''(x)$, what is the matrix that belongs to this map?

(I want to know the characteristic and minimal polynomial of $T$ and if $T$ is diagonalizable, but I thought I need to know the matrix first).

Comment: @user251257 I don't know how to find the matrix

Comment: Start with fixing a basis of $V$.   What's the natural basis you should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $V$ is a 4 dimensional vector space, and a basis of $V$ is $\lbrace 1,x,x^{2},x^{3} \rbrace$. $T(1)=1$, $T(x)=x$, $T(x^{2})=x^{2}+2$, $T(x^{3})=x^{3}+6x$

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2&0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &6\\
0 & 0 & 1 &0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &1\end{pmatrix}$$  is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the given basis. The characteristic polynomial is hence $(x-1)^{4}$ (I hope I didn't make any mistake!)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** A basis for $V$ is $B = \{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$. Compute $T(1), T(x), T(x^2), T(x^3)$, write the results in basis $B$ and put it in columns. For example, $T(1) = 1$, so the first column has $1$ followed by zeroes. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you write $p(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3=(a,b,c,d)$ then $T(p(x))=p(x)+p''(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+2c+6x=(a+2c)+(6+b)x+cx^2+dx^3=(a+2c,6+b,c,d)$, so the action of $T$ is $$T(p(x))=T(a,b,c,d)=(a+2c,6+b,c,d)$$
with this you will be able to find the matrix

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Your transformation acts as:
$$
T( ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d +6ax+2b =
$$
$$
= ax^3+bx^2+(6a+c)x+2b+d
$$

with respect to the standard basis this is the transformation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b\\c\\d\\
\end{bmatrix}
 \rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b\\6a+c\\2b+d\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
can you find the matrix that represents this transformation?